# Change recursive array into single array with same key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i want to know if it's possible to change an array structure, currently i'm receiving this array:

```
[{"ano":["2004","2006"]},{"ano":["2006",""]},{"ano":["2011",""]},{"ano":["2013",""]}]
```

I need those dates split one by row like this:

```
[{"ano":"2004"},{"ano":"2006"},{"ano":"2006"},{"ano":"2011"}]
```

So, basically i'm think i could clean empty and duplicated values, and then split the array or something?

I'm using PHP and MySQL SELECT to return those values like this:

```
while($ano = $pegaAno->fetchObject()){
    $ar1 = array("ano" => $ano->inicio);
    $ar2 = array("ano" => $ano->fim);
    $result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
    //print_r($result);
    array_push($return_arr,$result);
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can the array be created in the desired structure from the start? Or does it have to be changed from the array you are showing at the top`?

Comment: Hi @zedd, right now i'm requesting 2 columns from database, date_start and date_end, so it's coming 2 arrays, i've merged them recusively but it's returning json like the first array above, i need to return date_start and date_end values with the same key and remove duplicates, because i need to display a list of dates avaliable for that query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($ano = $pegaAno->fetchObject())
   array_push($return_arr, array("ano" => $ano->inicio), array("ano" => $ano->fim));
$return_arr = array_unique($return_arr);
```

Perhaps you want something like this? So you can have an array as

```
0 => [ "ano" => value ]
1 => [ "ano" => value ]
2 => [ "ano" => value ]
//etc...
```

Comment: You rock man, exactly what i needed, do you know how i can check for duplicates between both arrays and remove them?

Comment: Did not worked, maybe needed to remove duplicates before array_push?

Comment: @WilliamXavier it actually worked for me, can you show me how did you try?

Comment: I've tried it like this:

`array_push(array_unique($return_arr),array("ano" => $ano->inicio), array("ano" => $ano->fim));`

Comment: @WilliamXavier Modified the code, use it after the while :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this code

```
    $input[0]['anno'] = array("2004","2006");
    $input[1]['anno'] = array("2008","");
    $input[2]['anno'] = array("2002","2006");
    $input[3]['anno'] = array("2004","2013");
    $arr = array();   
    foreach ($input as $value) { 
    foreach ($value as $key =>  $value1) { 
        foreach ($value1 as  $value2) { 
            $arr[] = $value2;
        }   
    } 

    } 
    $resulted = array_filter(array_unique($arr));
    $resulted_array = array();
    foreach ($resulted as $value) { 
        $resulted_array[][$mainkey] = $value;
    }
    print_r($resulted_array);

//RESULT 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [anno] => 2004
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [anno] => 2006
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [anno] => 2008
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [anno] => 2002
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [anno] => 2013
        )

)
```

Comment: But then i have 2 arrays, should i merge them before?

Comment: if array are in same then first merge it .